# Matlab Runtime does not free memory after shut down

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have created a shared library using Matlab Compiler according to [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/) example. I have integrated that library into my C++ project. When I initialize the matlab runtime and library, the RAM consumption of my program increases drastically. The problem is that when I shut down the library and the matlab runtime the RAM consumption of the program does not reduce.

Comment: The later versions of Matlab do have some reported cases of extreme memory usage. You could try running it with the -nodesktop option to disable the GUI and just use the command line if the memory usage is too extreme

Comment: @ AruniRC The problem is not that matlab consume extreme amount of memory. The problem is that it does not free energy after I terminate it

Comment: @lnk, is the Matlab runtime itself terminated?

Comment: @ A. Donda Matlab runtime is "loaded" to my .exe program. I do it with this lines: mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0); mylibInitialize();. After that lines executed memory consumption increases and I can call matlab functions. To close matlab I use this lines: mylibTerminate(); mclTerminateApplication();. After that lines executed memory is not free. However if I try to call matlab function program gives an error. So I think that Matlab is terminated

Comment: @lnk, didn't catch your comment because with a space between @ and the name there is no notification. I can't comment on your code, but I'd suggest to use a process monitor to verify the Matlab runtime has been cleanly terminated.

Comment: Did you link to your DLL statically, or with LoadLibrary?   If with LoadLibrary, there's an excellent chance some internal statics/globals were populated and would be freed when you call FreeLibrary.